# How to write data in binary form to a file using extract and insert operators in a stream?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, fstream, binary-data

Opening a file with fstream:

```
std::fstream fileStream(obj.path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
```

Next, I write data to the file:

```
fileStream << this->m_path;
fileStream << this->m_name;
fileStream << this->m_owner;
```

Opening the file, I see the data is not in binary form.
Is this only possible using function write?

```
fileStream.write((char*)&m_owner, sizeof(std::string));
```

Comment: Stream inserters do **formatted output**. Yes, if you want unformatted output, you have to use unformatted output operations like `write()`.

Comment: `fileStream.write((char*)&m_owner, sizeof(std::string));` Is not going to work with a std::string. You end up saving one or more pointers and not the string itself

Comment: @drescherjm I rather inserted it for an example, the question is more about writing in binary form.